# How to write a function to find the class in a categorical variable with the highest average for a numerical column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd 
def category_with_highest_average (df,cat_column, num_column):

solution  = ''

test_case = category_with_highest_average(price_city_df,'city','price')
```

Is this as simple as .describe ? what am i missing here ?

Desired output:

[image: desired output]

Comment: You seem to need `groupby` and `avg`.

Comment: Please update your question to be (more) readable (then also add the `pandas` tag). Also, please include one or multiple examples of input and desired output.

Comment: I linked a pic with the expected output  ! does that help ?

Comment: that helps for sure, but it would be better to just have it as text and not an image. I don't know pandas, but I suspect you have to actually write that function `category_with_highest_average`, maybe show what you have tried so far?